# How does git compare BLOBs when merging

Tags: git

How does git compare files, specificity BLOBs, when merging and find the place where BLOBs are different?  Assume that the file has been changed in two branches, and at the same location in the file, but differently. Does it compare each bit in one BLOB with same bit in another BLOB from beginning to end? Or compare byte to byte or some another algorithm?

Comment: Too lazy to go through it, bur here's the source https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/merge-blobs.c

Comment: @igor_rb Are you just trying to understand how it works, or do you have a problem with a particular file.  If so, is it well know type like a .png or .exe, or some custom file of your own?

Comment: I'm simply trying to understand, how it works.